# How to return boolean based on object value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, ecmascript-6

Trying to return boolean value if object rejectMessage contains the code that i have specified in checkErrorCodes method. it should return true if settlementCode matches its not returning  boolean value it is retuning whole isError function. Any idea or better approach to have this done ?

transformPrice.js

```
function transformPrice(oldDrugPrice) {
      let drugPrice =  {
            "drugName": "Metformin",
            "mailPrice": {
                "copayEmployer": "N/A",
                "totalQuantity": "90.0",
                "rejectMessage": [{
                    "settlementCode": "99",
                    "settlementDesc": "Not Covered: Call us - System could not process your request. Call us at the toll-free number on your benefit ID card.||Sin cobertura: Llámenos - El sistema no pudo procesar su solicitud. Llame al número gratuito que figura en su tarjeta de identificación de beneficios."
                }]
            },
            "retailPrice": {
                "copayEmployer": "N/A",
                "totalQuantity": "30.0"
            }
        },

      if (drugPrice.retailPrice.rejectMessage || drugPrice.mailPrice.rejectMessage.length ){
        const retailRejecrMsg = drugPrice.retailPrice.rejectMessage;
        const mailPriceMsg = drugPrice.mailPrice.rejectMessage;
         const retailErr = isErrorPresent(retailRejecrMsg);
         const mailErr =isErrorPresent(mailPriceMsg);

      }

      return drugPrice;
    }
```

isErrorPresent Method

```
function isErrorPresent (price) {
  const isError = function (element) {
    const bRet = checkErrorCodes(element);
    return (element.hasOwnProperty('settlementCode') && bRet)
  }

  return isError;
}
```

checkErrorCodes method

```
function checkErrorCodes(el){
  let bRet = false;
  const errorCodes = [
    10015,
    2356,
    225,
    224,
      99
  ]

  for (const err of errorCodes){

    if (err === el.settlementCode){

      bRet = true;
    }
  }
   return bRet;
}
```

Comment: Where should the `element` come from?

Comment: why isn't `settlementCode` an int?

Comment: @JonasWilms i have go through each retail/mail price rejectMessage array and see if settlementCode matches with the code. it should come from element

Comment: @depperm thats how backend is returning

Comment: I see a couple problems: `settlementCodes` vs. `settlementCode`, using `===` to compare string to number.

Comment: @JackA. fixed that issue still its not returning boolean value from isErrorPresent

Comment: i would appreciate if there is better approach using ES6 or lodash

Comment: function isErrorPresent is receiving (price) but using (element) instead inside function.

Answer (score 0):

how about calling the is error method

```
const mailErr =isErrorPresent(mailPriceMsg).call();
```

or change the isErrorPresent method

```
function isErrorPresent (price, element) {
    const bRet = checkErrorCodes(element);
    return (element.hasOwnProperty('settlementCode') && bRet)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the function isErrorPresent you are never calling the isError function. To call it you should:

```
return isError(price)
```

this will call the function with the argument price
so in your example this would look like:

```
function isErrorPresent (price) {
  const isError = function (element) {
    const bRet = checkErrorCodes(element);
    return (element.hasOwnProperty('settlementCode') && bRet)
  }

  return isError(price);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing here is creating a function that returns another function:

```
function isErrorPresent (price) {
  const isError = function (element) {
    const bRet = checkErrorCodes(element);
    return (element.hasOwnProperty('settlementCode') && bRet)
  }

  return isError;
}
```

If you look closely, you can see that `return isError` is actually returning a reference to a function, and not the result of the function after it has been called.

You could call the two functions like so: `isErrorPresent(price)(element)`

---

or define the function like so:

```
function isErrorPresent (price, element) {
    const bRet = checkErrorCodes(element);
    return (element.hasOwnProperty('settlementCode') && bRet);
}
```

and then call it like `isErrorPresent(price, element)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like that:

```js
function isErrorPresent (obj) {

  if(checkErrorCodes(obj) && obj.hasOwnProperty('settlementCode')){ //error code checked
    return obj; //return obj
  }
  return false; //no error found

}

function checkErrorCodes(el){
  const errorCodes = [
    10015,
    2356,
    225,
    224,
      99
  ]
  return errorCodes.includes(el.settlementCode);
}
```

That's the way I'd approach this. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have ran your code and found several issues:

- isErrorPresent Method return isError method not a value
- in transformPrice method you has some issues such as:

  - missing semicolon before If statement
  - rejectMessage is array you should access via index.
  - you did not check null for `retailRejecrMsg` and `mailPriceMsg`

Also I don't know what do you want after check Error, so I add value into drugPrice.mailErr and drugPrice.retailErr.

I have fixed, hope it help.

```js
function transformPrice() {
      let drugPrice =  {
            "drugName": "Metformin",
            "mailPrice": {
                "copayEmployer": "N/A",
                "totalQuantity": "90.0",
                "rejectMessage": [{
                    "settlementCode": "99",
                    "settlementDesc": "Not Covered: Call us - System could not process your request. Call us at the toll-free number on your benefit ID card.||Sin cobertura: Llámenos - El sistema no pudo procesar su solicitud. Llame al número gratuito que figura en su tarjeta de identificación de beneficios."
                }]
            },
            "retailPrice": {
                "copayEmployer": "N/A",
                "totalQuantity": "30.0"
            }
        };

      if (drugPrice.retailPrice.rejectMessage || drugPrice.mailPrice.rejectMessage.length ){
        const retailRejecrMsg = drugPrice.retailPrice.rejectMessage ? drugPrice.retailPrice.rejectMessage[0]: null;
        const mailPriceMsg = drugPrice.mailPrice.rejectMessage ? drugPrice.mailPrice.rejectMessage[0]: null;
        drugPrice.retailErr = !retailRejecrMsg ? true : isErrorPresent(retailRejecrMsg);
        drugPrice.mailErr = !mailPriceMsg ? true : isErrorPresent(mailPriceMsg);
      }

      return drugPrice;
}

function isErrorPresent (price) {
    const bRet = checkErrorCodes(price);
    return (price.hasOwnProperty('settlementCode') && bRet)
}

function checkErrorCodes(el){
  let bRet = false;
  const errorCodes = [
    10015,
    2356,
    225,
    224,
    99
  ]

  for (const err of errorCodes){
    if (err === el.settlementCode){
      bRet = true;
    }
  }
   return bRet;
}
console.log(transformPrice())
```